# NGINX: rewrite, proxy and cache a folder

Tags: nginx

I am new to NGINX and need to know how to do this in a special location (folder)

- remove all query parameters
- proxy request to another server
- cache the result locally for x minutes

Config snippet:

```
location /cache {
    rewrite /cache/([^/\?]) /cache/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://foo.bar/original/;
    expire 5m;
}
```

I already saw different ideas with overwriting `$args` and using `?` for arguments removal. But I could not get anything to work like expected.

E.g.

```
1. Request
---
Request: http://foo.bar/cache/text.css?abc=123
Rewrite: http://foo.bar/cache/text.css
Cache miss
Proxy:   http://fuzzu.buzzi/original/text.css
(store in local cache)
Expire:  http://foo.bar/cache/text.css (after 5min)

2. Request
---
Request: http://foo.bar/cache/text.css?abc=123
Rewrite: http://foo.bar/cache/text.css
Cache hit
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example we can try to implement?  I'm having trouble working out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I added an example =)

Comment: Thanks for the example, it makes life a little easier.  What's the general rule that translates `test.css` to `text.css`?

Comment: ouch... that's a late night typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @womble do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution myself:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=foo_bar:1m inactive=10m;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.bar;

    # DNS lookup
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    resolver_timeout 1s;

    # use regex to not forward query string
    location ~ ^/cache/(.*)$ {
        proxy_cache foo_bar;

        # cache key only with host + path but without query string
        proxy_cache_key $host$uri;

        # nginx should ignore cache headers but forward them
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

        proxy_cache_valid 5m;
        proxy_pass http://fuzzu.buzzi/original/$1;

        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

}
```